# How to make some specific items of a NSTableView in bold?

Tags: swift, xcode, nstableview

I would like to set some items of a non-editable, View Based NSTableView in bold. The items correspond to a specific index number of the array I use to populate the TableView.

I would like to set the change before the NSTableView is displayed to the users.

I tried to handle this change in this method but I can't find a way to do it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?
```

[image]

Comment: don't use that method. That is old school. You should use view-based tables. Return a view and set the text of your custom view (cell). For attributed text you will need an NSAttributedString.

Comment: Add a boolean property `isBold` to your model and bind `Table Cell View  -> objectValue.isBold` to `Font Bold` of the text field.

Comment: Since you are on OS X, you can use either `NSAttributedString` or Cocoa Bindings to bold it

Comment: @matt sorry I made a mistake in the question title, I edited it now

Comment: @user965972 `objectValueForColumn:row` is a contemporary data source method to be used for Cocoa Bindings with view based table views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If you don't want to use Cocoa Bindings

It's very similar on how you do it on iOS. Configure the cell's view in `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)`

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

    var daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    var boldDays = ["Monday", "Wednesday"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return daysOfWeek.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        // Assuming that you have set the cell view's Identifier in Interface Builder
        let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "myCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        let day = daysOfWeek[row]

        cell.textField?.stringValue = day
        if boldDays.contains(day) {
            let fontSize = NSFont.systemFontSize()
            cell.textField?.font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize)

            // if you require more extensive styling, it may be better to use NSMutableAttributedString
        }

        return cell
    }   
}
```

#### If you want to use Cocoa Bindings

Cocoa Bindings can make this very simple, but if you set the slightest things wrong, it's pretty hard to figure out where things went south. Heed the [warning from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html):

> Populating a table view using Cocoa bindings is considered an advanced topic. Although using bindings requires significantly less code—in some cases no code at all—the bindings are hard to see and debug if you aren’t familiar with the interface. It’s strongly suggested that you become comfortable with the techniques for managing table views programmatically before you decide to use Cocoa bindings.

Anyhow, here's how to do it. First, the code:

```
// The data model must inherit from NSObject for KVO compliance
class WeekDay : NSObject {
    var name: String
    var isBold: Bool

    init(name: String, isBold: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.isBold = isBold
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

    let daysOfWeek = [
        WeekDay(name: "Sunday"),
        WeekDay(name: "Monday", isBold: true),
        WeekDay(name: "Tuesday"),
        WeekDay(name: "Wednesday", isBold: true),
        WeekDay(name: "Thursday"),
        WeekDay(name: "Friday"),
        WeekDay(name: "Saturday")
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Then the Interface Builder config:

1. Make sure the **Table Column** and **Table Cell View** have the same identifier. Best is to leave both of them blank for automatic

[image: Table Column and Table Cell View identifier]

2. Select the **Table View**, bind Table Content to View Controller, Model Key Path = `self.daysOfWeek`

[image: Bind Table Content]

3. Select the **Table View Cell**, bind Value to Table Cell View (no kidding), Model Key Path = `objectValue.name`

[image: Bind Value]

4. Scroll down, bind Font Bold to Table Cell View, Model Key Path = `objectValue.isBold`

[image: Bind Font Bold]

---

Either way, you should end up with something like this:

[image: Result]

Polish as needed.

Comment: Thank you Code Different for this great tutorial.